# JavaFX: editable TableView without JavaFX-style properties

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I got very angry with Oracle today after reading lots of editable TableView solutions involving setOnEditCommit, which is just NOT the right way it should be done.

Following is a much better and simpler solution I found after digging the JavaFX source:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### To create TableView:

```java
BorderPaneBuilder.create()
    .top(ToolBarBuilder.create()
        .items(ButtonBuilder.create()
            .text("Add New Row")
            .onAction(e -> backendItemList.add(new MyItem("<NEW>", "<NEW>")))
            .build())
        .build())
    .center(
        TableViewBuilder.<CustomColumnNameMapping> create()
            .items(backendItemList)
            .editable(true)
            .columns(
                TableColumnBuilder.<CustomColumnNameMapping, String> create()
                    .text("Column1 for property1")
                    .cellValueFactory(new WritablePropertyValueFactory<>("property1"))
                    .cellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn())
                    .editable(true)
                    .build(),
                TableColumnBuilder.<CustomColumnNameMapping, String> create()
                    .text("Column2 for property2")
                    .cellValueFactory(new WritablePropertyValueFactory<>("property2"))
                    .cellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn())
                    .editable(true)
                    .build())
            .build())
    .build();
```

### WritablePropertyValueFactory.java:

```java
import javafx.beans.NamedArg;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.CellDataFeatures;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.util.Callback;
import sun.util.logging.PlatformLogger;
import sun.util.logging.PlatformLogger.Level;

import com.sun.javafx.property.PropertyReference;
import com.sun.javafx.scene.control.Logging;

// Original code from PropertyValueFactory
// Replacing ReadOnlyObjectWrapper with new ReadableWritableObservableValue
public class WritablePropertyValueFactory<S, T> implements Callback<CellDataFeatures<S, T>, ObservableValue<T>>
{
    private final String property;

    private Class<?> columnClass;
    private String previousProperty;
    private PropertyReference<T> propertyRef;

    public WritablePropertyValueFactory(@NamedArg("property") String property)
    {
        this.property = property;
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public ObservableValue<T> call(CellDataFeatures<S, T> param)
    {
        return getCellDataReflectively((T) param.getValue());
    }

    public final String getProperty()
    {
        return this.property;
    }

    private ObservableValue<T> getCellDataReflectively(T rowData)
    {
        if (getProperty() == null || getProperty().isEmpty() || rowData == null)
            return null;
        try
        {
            if (this.columnClass == null || this.previousProperty == null ||
                    !this.columnClass.equals(rowData.getClass()) ||
                    !this.previousProperty.equals(getProperty()))
            {
                this.columnClass = rowData.getClass();
                this.previousProperty = getProperty();
                this.propertyRef = new PropertyReference<T>(rowData.getClass(), getProperty());
            }
            if (this.propertyRef.hasProperty())
            {
                return this.propertyRef.getProperty(rowData);
            }
            else
            {
                // Create ReadableWritableObservableValue instead of ReadOnlyObjectWrapper
                return new ReadableWritableObservableValue<T>(
                        () -> this.propertyRef.get(rowData),
                        (value) -> this.propertyRef.set(rowData, value));
            }
        }
        catch (IllegalStateException e)
        {
            final PlatformLogger logger = Logging.getControlsLogger();
            if (logger.isLoggable(Level.WARNING))
            {
                logger.finest("Can not retrieve property '" + getProperty() +
                        "' in PropertyValueFactory: " + this +
                        " with provided class type: " + rowData.getClass(), e);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

### ReadableWritableObservableValue.java

```java
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

import javafx.beans.InvalidationListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.beans.value.WritableValue;

public class ReadableWritableObservableValue<T> implements ObservableValue<T>, WritableValue<T>
{
    protected final Supplier<T> getter;
    protected final Consumer<T> setter;

    public ReadableWritableObservableValue(Supplier<T> getter, Consumer<T> setter)
    {
        this.getter = getter;
        this.setter = setter;
    }

    @Override
    public void addListener(InvalidationListener listener)
    {
        // useless (no property to listen)
    }

    @Override
    public void removeListener(InvalidationListener listener)
    {
        // useless (no property to listen)
    }

    @Override
    public void addListener(ChangeListener<? super T> listener)
    {
        // useless (no property to listen)
    }

    @Override
    public void removeListener(ChangeListener<? super T> listener)
    {
        // useless (no property to listen)
    }

    @Override
    public T getValue()
    {
        return this.getter.get();
    }

    @Override
    public void setValue(T value)
    {
        this.setter.accept(value);
    }
}
```

PS: The key is to return a WritableValue from callback, see TableColumn#DEFAULT_EDIT_COMMIT_HANDLER.

Comment: There are some problems with this code: you are using both classes that have been deprecated in JavaFX 8 (the builder classes), and classes that are not part of the public API (`PropertyReference`, for example), which could well be removed in future releases.

Comment: I'm aware of that but they still beat FXML due to very poor tooling of the latter. The behavior of various controls with WritableValue is also undocumented. However, at worst it could be replaced at runtime by a normal JavaFX binding, with no change in the code calling it.

Comment: This seems way more complicated than `setOnEditCommit` though: see my answer. What is your objection to the standard solution?

Comment: It's only more complicated in the beginning to create the necessary foundation. Afterwards it's much simpler because you just bind a column to property and it'd work; the solution can also be extended with custom converters, specified via global registry or annotation. The *standard* solution requires more code, which could and should have been eliminated through reflection and conventions. (and the cellFactory calls should be eliminated too, since it could be detected from property types most of time).

Comment: Not sure I really buy that. There are many facets to simplicity/complexity: for example my solution is compile-time typesafe. The standard solution is designed for JavaFX-style beans (using observable properties) and works very cleanly in that use case, and there are mechanisms for use cases outside that. Your solution is aimed at a slightly different standard (models using a JavaBean convention), you'd still need quite a bit of code for models that didn't fit that use case (e.g. columns representing properties of properties, maps, etc).

Comment: That's true. I ended up having new models utilizing JavaFX properties. However even those are not good enough - there is no direct way to do selection binding with properties as the final target (for two-way binding to input controls).

Answer (score 5):

I think your solution seems far more complicated than using `setOnEditCommit`. For example (using the usual contact table type example that Oracle uses), given a standard `Person` JavaBean:

```
public class Person {
    private String firstName ;
    private String lastName ;

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return firstName + " " + lastName ;
    }
}
```

This code creates an editable table that updates the Java beans:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyStringWrapper;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>();

        TableColumn<Person, String> firstNameCol = new TableColumn<>("First Name");

        firstNameCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        firstNameCol.setOnEditCommit(
                event -> event.getRowValue().setFirstName(event.getNewValue()));
        firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(data -> new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(data.getValue().getFirstName()));

        TableColumn<Person, String> lastNameCol = new TableColumn<>("Last Name");
        lastNameCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        lastNameCol.setOnEditCommit(
                event -> event.getRowValue().setLastName(event.getNewValue()));
        lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(data -> new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(data.getValue().getLastName()));

        table.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol);
        table.setEditable(true);

        Button button = new Button("Show data");
        button.setOnAction(event -> table.getItems().forEach(System.out::println));

        HBox controls = new HBox(5, button);

        root.setCenter(table);
        root.setBottom(controls);

        table.getItems().addAll(
                new Person("Jacob", "Smith"),
                new Person("Isabella", "Johnson"),
                new Person("Ethan", "Williams"),
                new Person("Emma", "Jones"),
                new Person("Michael", "Brown")
        );

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

This code also avoids any non-public API classes. I agree that the builder classes are a little more elegant, but they have been [deprecated for good reason](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/openjfx-dev/2013-March/006725.html).

Additionally, this also avoids reflection, unlike the `WritablePropertyValueFactory` class (or the `PropertyValueFactory` API class), so it likely performs better.

Comment: Reflection could be further optimized automatically to match native performance by creating accessor JVM code at runtime to call property getters and setters. My point is that it's WRONG to tell the API how to do things that it could discover by itself.

Comment: You can also experiment with `firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory( data -> JavaBeanStringPropertyBuilder.create().bean(data.getValue()).name("firstName").build());` which also eliminates the "here's what to do when the editing completes" code. I haven't thought through whether or not that creates a memory leak though.

Comment: That `.name()` part smells like "magic string", avoid when possibile.